# how does laravel know if the user is logged in?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to learn Laravel fundamentals, and I have a question in my mind. How does Laravel know if the user has logged in? Does laravel use user-owned sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default, it uses a stateful approach for sessions. It saves data at `storage/framework/sessions`. Learn more at `https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session`

And in the stateless approach, it doesn't know anything. It just looks up the header and checks if authentication key is signed by appropriate key